# Can SSH but not access EC2-hosted site

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've got a site I'm building that's hosted on an Amazon EC2 server with an elastic IP address. It worked fine until recently (took a break for about a week between working on it, so I'm not sure when it went wonky). I noticed today that although I can SSH into the server no problem, I cannot access the site itself via a web browser. Tried with the domain name, tried with the elastic IP, and tried with the AWS ec2 public DNS.

The SSH was done to the domain name.

Help? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: OK, so I'm an idiot. Apache crashed on me. This is what happens when people run their own servers who probably shouldn't.

Comment: Maybe apache or whatever server software you're running stopped working?

Answer (score 2):

ssh has nothing to do with http and https. Different ports, different protocols, even if they do basically use the same encryption schemes. SSH in and make sure that Apache is running, and listening on the proper ports, and that the ports are not firewalled somehow.